# HOW to solve "Compile error: Type mismatch" with own file ocx in VB6

Tags: vb6, activex, ocx

I have an ActiveX named GridEntry.ocx I found it from the download link [GridEntry.ocx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-He3B_8lkDIOsQgdo_lYMVgHTiNjuMF1/view?usp=drivesdk)

I want to use it to make a software.
but I'm having trouble, and getting an error message. "Compile error: Type mismatch"
my code

```
Private Sub GridEntry1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer, Row As Integer, Col As Byte)
If KeyAscii = 13 Then
Post = GridEntry1.CellFocus(0, 1)
 With GridEntry1
  .Caption = "TEST"
  End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: On what line do you see an error?

Comment: in this line `Post = GridEntry1.CellFocus(0, 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
Private Sub GridEntry1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer, Row As Integer, Col As Byte)
If KeyAscii = 13 Then
Call  GridEntry1.CellFocus(0, 1)
 With GridEntry1
  .Caption = "TEST"
  End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: wow great, your solution worked fine. Thank you very much for your help 

Comment: hi Volkan, thanks for your answer. Can you explain why your solution works? (What is `Post` versus `Call`?)

Comment: "Call" only executes function or sub